# Problem on CentOS 8 with creating VDO - Kernel module kvdo not installed

Tags: centos, kernel, module

When trying to create vdo I get the following message:

```
# vdo create --name=vdo1 --device=/dev/sdb2 --vdoLogicalSize=1T
Creating VDO vdo1
vdo: ERROR - Kernel module kvdo not installed
vdo: ERROR - modprobe: FATAL: Module kvdo not found in directory /lib/modules/4.18.0-240.1.1.el8_3.x86_64
```

Anybody know why I get the error and how I can fix it?

I also installed additional packages with

```
# dnf install *4.18.0-240.1.1.el8* -y
```

It installed some more packages including some kernel packages but I still get the error.

And all packages also installed and vdo is enabled as well:

```
# systemctl status vdo
● vdo.service - VDO volume services
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/vdo.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Fri 2020-12-11 12:44:55 UTC; 3h 49min ago
  Process: 782 ExecStart=/usr/bin/vdo start --all --confFile /etc/vdoconf.yml (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 782 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 23438)
   Memory: 0B
   CGroup: /system.slice/vdo.service

Dec 11 12:44:53 node systemd[1]: Starting VDO volume services...
Dec 11 12:44:55 node systemd[1]: Started VDO volume services.

# rpm -qa | grep -i vdo
vdo-6.2.3.114-14.el8.x86_64
alsa-plugins-vdownmix-1.1.9-1.el8.x86_64
vdo-support-6.2.3.114-14.el8.x86_64
kmod-kvdo-6.2.2.117-65.el8.x86_64
libblockdev-vdo-2.24-1.el8.x86_64
```

Comment: Awaiting an answer to this also. It worked fine two weeks ago but after update yesterday, it is broken.

Comment: https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=17928 provides a solution but it is not a proper fix per se.

Comment: Reboot as mentioned on this site https://www.tecmint.com/create-a-vdo-volume-on-a-storage-device-on-rhel-8/ also didn't help, will try the new packages then @DavDav

Comment: Other useful page: https://www.centlinux.com/2019/12/configure-virtual-data-optimizer-vdo-centos-8.html

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on Oracle Linux 8, after running updates. It seems the latest kmod-kvdo package does not contain the kvdo kernel module for the newer kernels. This can be verified by querying the latest kmod-kvdo package (find the version first with `dnf list kmod-kvdo`):

```
rpm -ql kmod-kvdo-6.2.8.7-88.0.1.el8
/etc/depmod.d/kvdo.conf
/lib/modules/4.18.0-477.el8.x86_64
/lib/modules/4.18.0-477.el8.x86_64/extra
/lib/modules/4.18.0-477.el8.x86_64/extra/kmod-kvdo
/lib/modules/4.18.0-477.el8.x86_64/extra/kmod-kvdo/uds
/lib/modules/4.18.0-477.el8.x86_64/extra/kmod-kvdo/uds/uds.ko
/lib/modules/4.18.0-477.el8.x86_64/extra/kmod-kvdo/vdo
/lib/modules/4.18.0-477.el8.x86_64/extra/kmod-kvdo/vdo/kvdo.ko
```

My active kernel `5.4.17-2136.320.7.1.el8uek.x86_64` is not on the list.

To get VDO running, I changed with grubby the active kernel to be `4.18.0-477.el8.x86_64`, and rebooted. Hopefully they will fix kmod-kvdo soon.

Answer (score 0):

On another host I also got the following error:

```
Creating VDO vdo1
vdo: ERROR - Found existing signature on /dev/disk/by-id/usb-iOS_devi_FLASH_DRIVE_00000000CY02-0:0-part1 at offset 0: LABEL="(null)" UUID="c5d18b8a-7512-4193-af06-3032d519e4e0" TYPE="xfs" USAGE="filesystem".
```

After created a new partition on the disk

```
# fdisk /dev/sdb

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.32.1).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.


Command (m for help): n
Partition number (2-128, default 2):
First sector (10487808-262143966, default 10487808):
Last sector, +sectors or +size{K,M,G,T,P} (10487808-262143966, default 262143966): +10G

Created a new partition 2 of type 'Linux filesystem' and of size 10 GiB.
Partition #2 contains a stratis signature.

Do you want to remove the signature? [Y]es/[N]o: y

The signature will be removed by a write command.

Command (m for help): w
The partition table has been altered.
Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.
Syncing disks.


# partprobe
# lsblk
NAME          MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
....
sdb             8:16   1   125G  0 disk
....
└─sdb2          8:18   1    10G  0 part
```

As you could see my previously created tests with stratis, some details still remained on the disk partitions somehow. So I also removed those in fdisk.
After I could finally create the vdo:

```
# vdo create --name=vdo1 --device=/dev/sdb2 --vdoLogicalSize=1T
Creating VDO vdo1
      The VDO volume can address 6 GB in 3 data slabs, each 2 GB.
      It can grow to address at most 16 TB of physical storage in 8192 slabs.
      If a larger maximum size might be needed, use bigger slabs.
Starting VDO vdo1
Starting compression on VDO vdo1
VDO instance 0 volume is ready at /dev/mapper/vdo1
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue as well and traced down to inconsistent repositoryies.
If you upgrade entire CentOS with working VDO, it will break. I tried again today.
Since this issue is present for weeks/months, I made a solution that is not breaking with upgrades. It is easy to remove as well once this issue got fixed.

My OS Details of a affected virtual machine:

```
root@vm12 tests]# rpm -qa | grep -e vdo -e release
epel-release-8-10.el8.noarch
kmod-kvdo-6.2.2.117-65.el8.x86_64
centos-linux-release-8.3-1.2011.el8.noarch
vdo-6.2.3.114-14.el8.x86_64
[root@vm12 tests]# cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 8.3.2011
[root@vm12 tests]# dnf upgrade
Last metadata expiration check: 0:06:25 ago on Wed 06 Jan 2021 09:49:08 AM CET.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

Install the fix (modified repo) and repair os:

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/joe-speedboat/ansible.vdo_nfs_appliance/main/templates/CentOS-Stream-vdo.repo.j2 > /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Stream-vdo.repo
dnf makecache
dnf upgrade
reboot
```

Remove the fix (once the vdo packages are not taken from baseos-vdo repo anymore):

```
rm -f /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Stream-vdo.repo
```

BTW, feel free to use my whole ansible role to setup a vdo based storage appliance. But please RTFM first :-)

https://galaxy.ansible.com/joe-speedboat/ansible_vdo_nfs_appliance

BR Chris